# Where is my mistake in showing $\nabla \mathbf{a}^{T}\mathbf{x}=a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, fake-proofs

Let $f:=\mathbf{a}^{T}\mathbf{x}$. The claim that:
$$\nabla f=\nabla\mathbf{a}^{T}\mathbf{x}=\|\mathbf{a}\|_{1}=a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}\tag{1}$$
is false where in fact the true answer is $\mathbf{a}^{T}$.

Now one would argue that the correct answer is true by simply considering $\mathbf{a}$ to be just a scalar). However, I ended up proving $(1)$ and therefore I would request someone to indicate for me where in my attempt I made a mistake:
\begin{align}
\nabla f&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}}\mathbf{a}^{T}\mathbf{x}\tag{2}\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}x_{i}\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x_{i}}x_{i}\tag{4}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\tag{5}\\
&=\|\mathbf{a}\|_{1}\tag{6}
\end{align}

Comment: $\nabla f$ is a vector quantity, not a scalar. So look for the first step which has incorrect type / dimension.

Comment: hmm I see step 4 then doesn't make sense. For the actual proof can we include $\nabla$ inside the summation since derivatives in higher orders are also linear operators? @aschepler

Comment: As you've noted, (4) overuses $i$; you really need more than one index species here viz.$$(\nabla(a\cdot x))_i=\partial_i(a_jx_j)=a_j\partial_ix_j=a_j\delta_{ij}=a_i.$$

Comment: Ohh I see this is a really elegant short way to understand it. Thank you @J.G. and aschepler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Einstein summation,
$$\boldsymbol{a^\top x}=a_ix^i \\ \nabla_j(a_ix^i)=a^i\nabla_j x^i \\ =a^i\delta^i_j \\ =a_j$$
$a_j$ is the $j$th entry in the index-lowered or transposed version of $\boldsymbol a$. So
$$\nabla(\boldsymbol{a^\top x})=\boldsymbol {a^\top}$$

Your mistake was writing
$$\nabla \overset{?}{=}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\boldsymbol x}\neq \sum_i \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx^i}$$
It is in fact
$$\nabla=\sum_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\boldsymbol e_i$$